# How do you convert seconds (array) since specific time in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, datetime, timedelta

I try to convert second data since *1993/01/01* like this

```
time = [7.57382412e+08, 7.57382436e+08, 7.57382461e+08, ...,
   7.88918357e+08, 7.88918381e+08, 7.88918406e+08]
```

*I can convert it one by one like this*

```
datetime.datetime(1993,1,1) + datetime.timedelta(seconds=time[0])
```

*If I enter the array into `timedelta`*

```
datetime.datetime(1993,1,1) + datetime.timedelta(seconds=time)
```

It is showing a *TypeError*:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta seconds component: numpy.ndarray
```

How can I figure it out ?

Comment: You have to loop through the list

Comment: Note that Python will treat the starting point as *local time* if you don't set a time zone (e.g. as UTC, `tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc`).

Answer (score 1):

Try using list comprehension as below:

```
[datetime.datetime(1993,1,1) + datetime.timedelta(seconds=each) for each in time]
```

[image]